# Creating Windows Applications in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Where can I get a full tutorial or course needed so as to learn everything when coding a win 10 application on visual basic...or get all windows 10 applications libraries/sdk

Comment: Things like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/?view=vs-2019 are all over the search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! This is where you can start: [How to create an application in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019), but to know everything about Visual Basic you'll have to do some research on knowledge bases. For instance my favorite knowledge base is [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tutorialslibrary.htm), because it not only has everything about programming logged into one 'place', but it also shows custom code examples to give better understanding about the different topics. [This page on Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/index.htm) explains everything about VB, and it's very compact.

Comment: Well that was very helpful though there's one thing I didn't find,lets say I'm creating a windows software in which I  added a button which when clicked I need it to open my laptop's camera directly. Where can I find such codes.